# what is the difference between notifyDataSetChanged and add(T object) or addAll(T... items) methods in array adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I'm trying to learn List view and adapters, made a very basic app to learn in which I have a button that inserts a String object to the data source of an array adapter and the other view is list view which shows this data set. add() and addAll() method apends the data to the data set but when I do that list view shows it but I didn't call notifyDataSetChanged method, so why list view refreshed itself and if it did so then why do I need the method? Could anyone help me by giving some clarity? add(), addAll() and insert() methods already making the list view show the new added data but how? so what's the difference?

the app's only layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/insert_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="insert data"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the main activity code:

```
package famiddle.smart.apps.learningandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button insertButton;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add("hello world");
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    insertButton = findViewById(R.id.insert_button);
    insertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           adapter.add("hi there");
        }
    });


}

}
```

Comment: When you use `ArrayAdapter`'s `add()`, `addAll()`, etc., methods, it handles calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` itself internally, which is why your list updates without calling it yourself. You only need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you've changed the dataset directly yourself, instead of using those `ArrayAdapter` methods.

Comment: @Mike M. Thanks for ur comment, I think what you are saying is makes sense. I was thinking about it too.

Comment: @Mike M. Calling add or addAll method doesn't change the data, but call notify method if u change the data. Right?

Comment: "Calling add or addAll method doesn't change the data" – It will change the dataset that `ArrayAdapter` keeps internally, unless you've overridden those to do otherwise. "call notify method if u change the data." – Yeah, if you add something directly to the `ArrayList`, for example.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Now I understood it completely. Next goal simple cursor adapter! Will try my best to understand how to change cursor from null to some table data n to make adapter view show d data.